# Singularities of Composition of Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition, singularity

We are learning about singularities in my Complex Analysis course right now. I understand what it means to be each type of singularity however, a question I had was about the singularities of composition functions. In better words:

Let $f$ be holomorphic on $U=D(P,r)/\{P\}$ and $g$ be holomorphic on $f(U)$. Then if f has a singularity (removable, pole, essential, etc.) at $P$, does that imply that $g\circ f$ has one also?

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, $g$ needs to be holomorphic on $f(U)$, not on $U$. Unless $f$ maps $U$ into itself, the behavior of $g$ on $U$ is immaterial. With that correction:

If $f$ has a removable singularity at $P$, and if $g$ is holomorphic at $\lim_{z\to P}f(z)$, then $g\circ f$ has a removable singularity at $P$.

If $f$ has a pole at $P$, then the behavior of $g\circ f$ at $P$ is the same as the behavior of $g(1/z)$ at $z = 0$. For example,

- $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ has a removable singularity at $P$,
- $(f(z))^2$ has a pole at $P$, and
- $e^{f(z)}$ has an essential singularity.

Lastly, if $f$ has an essential singularity and $g$ is not constant, then $g\circ f$ will have an essential singularity. The easiest way to see this is by means of a fairly high-powered theorem: $f(V)$ is dense in $\Bbb C$ for every deleted neighborhood $V$ of $P$ (in fact $f(V)$ includes all of $\Bbb C$ except possibly for two points). From this it follows that $g(\overline{f(V)})$ includes the entire range of $g$, which does not occur for removable singularities or poles (since $g$ is not constant). Therefore $P$ has to be an essential singularity of $g\circ f$.

Comment: perfect. Thanks so much! That makes sense using those examples.

Comment: I have another question. If we were going to prove the first case, with the removable singularity, how would we go about that? I tried using the composition of Laurent series and making a coefficient argument. It seems to work but is there an easier way to think about this?

Comment: If $f$ has a removable singularity at $P$, then $f$ can be extended to a function $f_0$ that is holomorphic at $P$. Therefore $g\circ f_0$ is holomorphic at $P$, and $g\circ f$ is its restriction obtained by removing $P$ again. $\lim_{z\to P} g\circ f(z) = \lim_{z\to P} g\circ f_0(z) =  g\circ f_0(P)$.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I have a question. If $f$ has isolated singularity at $z=a$ and $g$ is analytic then does $g\circ f$ has isolated singularity at $z=a$ ? What about for non-isolated ? Can you please help me in this?

Comment: @Empty - The behavior of $g\circ f$ at isolated singularities of $f$ is *exactly* what this post discusses. Read it to find the answer. If you cannot figure something out, *ask about the specific issue that is causing confusion*, instead of just reiterating the question it answers. As for non-isolated singularities, *what do you think*?

Comment: @PaulSinclair  Your answer is clear enough to me for removable/pole/essential singularities. I have a specific problem,
"Discuss the nature of singularity of the function $\cos(1/\sin(1/z))$ at $z=0$."
Here take $g=\cos z$, which is entire and $f=1/\sin(1/z)$, it is clear to me that $f$ has simple pole at $1/n\pi$, and limit point of poles is $0$, which is $\textbf{non-isolated essential singularity}$ of $f$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair It is also clear to me that, $g\circ f$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$. My question, "is this singularity isolated or non-isolated for the function $g\circ f$ ?"

Comment: As you say, $f$ has a pole - a singularity - at $\frac 1{n\pi}$ for all $n \in \Bbb Z, n\ne 0$. Note in my discussion above that $g\circ f$ has a singularity wherever $f$ has a singularity, And in fact, the behavior of $g \circ f$ at a pole of $f$ is the behavior of $g$ at $\infty$, which in this case is an essential singularity. So $g\circ f$ has a singularity at each $z=\frac 1{n\pi}$. Evidently, the singularity at $z = 0$ is not isolated.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Sorry, but still, I am not getting why $z=0$ is non-isolated for $g\circ f$ ? Except this everything is clear to me.
Do you mean that, "if $f$ has non-isolated singularity at $P$ then $g\circ f$ has also the same" ?

Comment: What does it mean for a singularity to be isolated? It means that there is some neighborhood of that singularity where the function is analytic except at that one point. Is this true for this function at $z=0$? No! Every neighborhood of $z = 0$ contains infinitely many of the points $\frac 1{n\pi}$, which are also singularities.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes. From the definition of isolated singularity, it is clear that $f$ has non-isolated singularity at $z=0$. So for $g\circ f$ also the same?

Comment: I was discussing $g\circ f$, which you already admitted you recognize has a singularity at $z = 0$ and singularities at each $z = \frac 1{n\pi}$,

Comment: @PaulSinclair Precisely, my question is the following result is true or false?:
" if $f$ has isolated ( / non-isolated) singularity at $P$ and $g$ is entire function then $g\circ f$ has isolated (/ non-isolated) singularity at $P$."

Comment: And I have provided *everything* needed, have discussed what needs to be considered, have shown you why it is true and have applied it directly to the specific problem you said you were working on. Yet you have ignored what I have said, and just keep reiterating a question that has already been answered. I am DONE.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I am really sorry. a final question. Can you please provide me some books or class notes, or research papers which includes the proof of these results(given in your main answer)? Actually I am reading these area , I want to read the proofs. It will be a great help for me. I have searched in google, but not getting the proofs.

Comment: @PaulSinclair can you give me bit hint on "includes the entire range of g, which does not occur for removable singularities or poles "

Comment: What is it that you do not understand about the phrase and need a "hint" on? Why it is true? If so, then my hint is to read the full paragraph leading up to that phrase where I explain exactly that. The more powerful of the results I mentions (that the image of any neighorhood of an essential singularity is all of $\Bbb C$ except possibly two points is "Picard's theorem". The weaker "dense in $\Bbb C$" version is also named, but I do not recall the name.